# Sum 2 tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a var that looks like a list of tuples.

```
print var
```

show me

```
(6,)
(3,)
```

I do not really understand which type of var it is but I think this a kind of a tuple, a double tuple ?

Anyway, I want the sum of thi, in this case `9`

I already tried differents things like

```
print(sum(var))

#Or

list = list(var)
print(sum(list))

#Or

for f in var:
    test+=f
print(test)
```

and many more ...
But I still have

```
6
3
```

Or

```
[6]
[3]
```

Comment: what is the result of `type(var)`?

Comment: *I do not really understand which type of var it is* - verify with `type(var)`

Comment: It's clearly a double tuple dude

Comment: I'm betting that `var` is `str("(6,)\n(3,)")`

Comment: Then `test+=f` would not work, or at least give different results than 6 and 3. Errors if test is not a string, and returns the same string if it is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The result is 2 tuples

Comment: @Raccoon that is unlikely, unless you have a custom class named '2 tuples'. It should output `<class 'str'>` or similar

Comment: @TimCastelijns The result of `print(type(var))` is `<class 'tuple'><class 'tuple'>`

Comment: How is that possible? Could there be a class with a special metaclass that overrides the \_\_repr\_\_ method? If that is the case, how is the instantiating class supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution

```
row = cursor.fetchone()

while row is not None:
    var += row[0]
    row = cursor.fetchone() 

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Try nesting sum and list:

```
sum(list(first_tuple + second_tuple))
```

Comment: I only have one var which contain 2 tuples

Comment: So whats the type of var?

Comment: print(type(var)) give me `<class 'tuple'><class 'tuple'>`

Comment: Use this `print(type(var))` and tell us the output

Comment: @Raccoon What is the source of var. I mean from where its value come and you assign it to var.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tuple, then you can use:

```
print(sum([pair[0] for pair in var]))
```

Comment: It gave me this error `int object is not subscriptable`

Comment: So you don't have a tuple of tuples. What happens if you run print([pair for pair in var])?